# See view in tab bar when login success

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have 4 tabs in Tabbar View Controller in storyboard. When open app tab 1 appear and when tap tab 2-4 I want to show modal view for login. When login success, app will show view in tab 2-4. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not provide information on how you want to make a check if the user is logged in. but anyway, here is what i did with `Firebase`

in tab 2-4, check if user is logged in in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        if let user = user {

        } else {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let signInViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignIn")
            self.presentViewController(signInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    })     
}
```

once the view is loaded, it will check if the user is logged in, if not present the viewcontroller `SignIn`

once logged in is completed, you just have to dismiss the viewcontroller and it would return to which tab that the user clicked on previously

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I used Facebook and Twitter login but your answer work for me! Thanks :D